# Get server side cookie in nextjs getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, next.js, jwt

Im trying to make authentication for my Next.js website.

i have created a signin endpoint in `/api/users/signin` and inside that after verfying the user, i generate a JWT token and save it with the following:

```
res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", `token=${token}; HttpOnly; Secure`);
```

Now what im trying to do is: im trying to access this token from `/pages/login`, using getServerSideProps.
how can i do that ? can i even have access to the cookies that are set into `/api/users/signin` from `/pages/login`?

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
  console.log(context.req.headers.cookie);
  const response = await checkAuth(context.req.headers);
  return {
    props: {
      response,
    },
  };
}
```

If im wrong, whats the right approach ?
Note: i checked the `/api/users/signin` and the cookie is set perfectly and there is no issue with the api endpoint.

Comment: I'd recommend you use passport.js to do this for you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend utilizing [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware). You can create a `middleware.ts` file in the same level as your `pages` directory and check for a given cookie in the paths that you want to run the middleware on with `matcher`. For example, if you would want to show an admin page if only a `token` exists, your middleware could look something like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // this will check if there is a value for the cookie named token
  // if it exists it will load the page
  if (request.cookies.get('token')?.value) return NextResponse.next();

  // if the cookie does not exist, you can redirect anywhere you want
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/<change-this-to-whatever>', request.url));
}

// this will make sure that the middleware only runs on /pages/admin
// you can change it whatever you want
export const config = {
  matcher: '/admin',
};
```